# Ativação do Leitor de Código de Barras na Vertical - Zxing

Tags: android

desenvolvi uma aplicação android onde ativa o leitor de código de barras para ler código de barras de produtos.

O que estou achando estranho é que ao ativar o scanner ele muda a posição para horizontal ou seja, o leitor fica deitado.

Como faço para deixar a orientação dele na vertical sem mudar a orientação ?

Answer (score 1):

A orientação é imposta pela Activity usada para ler o código.
Na declaração dela, no [Manifest.xml](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/AndroidManifest.xml#L46), é usado **android:screenOrientation="[sensorLandscape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)".**

Como essa Activity faz parte do Zxing não tem como(não deve) alterá-lo.

Answer (score -1):

Coloca a activity do leitor em portrait.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Não irá funcionar, veja a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288904/2541)